# Как обратится внутрь блока цикла? Sum не видит sum внутри блока цикла

Tags: java, циклы

```java
for (int j = 0; j < 14; j = j + 2) {                      // сумма четных индексов
    int sum = 0;
    sum = sum + array[j];
} 
System.out.println("Chet =" + sum);

            {
for (int i = 1; i < 14; i = i + 2) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum = sum + array[i];
}
System.out.println("Nechet =" + sum);
```

Comment: Вынесите переменую sum за циклы и она будет видна. Дла суммы нечетных чисел oddSum, а для четных evenSum.

Comment: Тогда sum не будет работать. Sum считает сумму массива через инкримент i

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! Вывел за циклы, я не инициализировал int sum перед циклом, а выполнял после, в этом ошибка была

Comment: [Почитайте](https://javarush.com/quests/lectures/questsyntax.level02.lecture04) про видимость переменных, чтобы в будущем не было вопросов. Это очень важная тема.

Comment: Также в представленном коде другая распространённая ошибка -- использование  некой константы вместо длины массива `arr.length`, что может привести к `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, если длина массива меньше 14, или к неполным вычислениям.  Также часть кода по вычислению суммы дублируется и отличается только начальным индексом.

Comment: @a1isher Не следует поощрять ChatGPT-шные ответы вообще, и в частности данный, который по сути ничем не отличается от первого же комментария Руслана.

Comment: @NowhereMan Окей, убрал галочку. Как понять что ответил ChatGPT?

Comment: Пролетарским чутьём :)  В целом, чувствуется по роботизированной вежливости и нейтральности, излишней многословности типа: _Здесь мы объявляем две переменные sumChet и sumNechet перед циклами и используем их внутри циклов для накопления суммы четных и нечетных индексов массива соответственно. Затем мы выводим значения этих переменных с помощью System.out.println()_

Comment: @a1isher, если вы смогли сами решить свою проблему, можете написать ответ с собственным решением (с учётом _всех_ комментариев), и через несколько дней принять его.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай инициализацию переменной `int sum = 0;` выше цикла. И, если я правильно понял, что твой массив из 15 элементов, небольшой совет, в условии цикла вместо `j < 14` используй `j < array.length`. И тоже для второго цикла.

Ошибка в том, что `int sum = 0;` внутри цикла на каждой его итерации обнуляется. Поэтому инициализируй переменную в области видимости выше уровнем.

`array.length` - возвращает количество элементов массива.

UPD: Для второго цикла либо снова обнули переменную использовав `sum = 0;` перед вторым циклом, либо используй другую.